# cURL POST --data-binary using content from URL?

Tags: post, curl

Is it possible to use content from a URL to do Curl -data-binary POST?

POST content from a file:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: plain/text" --data-binary "@file.txt"  http://somewhere.com
```

Is there a curl command can do like

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: plain/text" --data-binary "http://somefile.com/file"  "http://somewhere.com"
```

suppose http://somefile.com/file is a binary text file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
curl -s http://somefile.com/file | curl --data-binary @- http://somewhere.com
```

Comment: removing the superfluous "-X POST" would make it even nicer =)